# How can I disable a JFrame while another one is opened

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I have a JFrame that has some JLabels, and when I click any JLabel, it opens another JFrame but I want the other to stay disabled. First I did:

```java
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2.setVisible(true);
this.setEnabled(false);
```

Then I want to `setEnabled(true)` the 1st frame when I close the 2nd frame. What I did is giving the 2nd frame a JFrame attribute and giving a param JFrame in its Constructor, and with a WindowListener I use the method `windowClosing()` like this:

```java
public class My2ndJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    My1stJFrame frame;

    public My2ndJFrame(My1stJFrame frame) {

        this.frame = frame;
        //moreCodeWeDontNeedNow

    }

@Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

        frame.setEnabled(true);

    }
```

It works but I dont know if this is good programming practice, so I would like to know if there's a better way and if this is not good, why. Thank you.

Comment: Use a modal `JDialog` instead - see [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Thank you, but a JDialog is not good for what I want. Anyways it MUST be a JFrame, its for educational purposes ahah (my teacher wants me to use JFrame there, not JDialog)

Comment: There's no way to disable the frame itself.  You will have to disable all the individual components them selves, but this won't stop the user from switching between the windows or closing the first frame - this is what a `JDialog` will do

Comment: There's no way? I actually disabled the frame with setEnabled(false) and when i run the program, I cant switch to the enabled(false) frame :/

Comment: *"There's no way?"* Check again with the teacher. I suspect they wanted the students to **start** with a frame. This 'using two frames' is just silly when there are dialogs which provide the *exact functionality required.* So go back to the advice in the first comment by @MadProgrammer.